# how sanitizer javascript function inside html string

Tags: javascript, angular, sanitizer

please, i need your help....soon

i have this code line in Angular 6:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {


this.errorMessageMain = 'Lo sentimos, ocurrió un error, debe <a (click)=\"goUpdate()\">actualizar</a>.';
this.errorMessageMain = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.errorMessageMain);
```

my HTML code for show the result is:

```
<div [innerHTML]="errorMessageMain"></div>
```

and the function code is so simple:

```
goUpdate() {    
alert("Hola Mundo"); 
  }
```

don't work .... how could i use satinizer the call goUpdate() function  ????

please....

Comment: That's not supported

Comment: Try with: `this.errorMessageMain = 'Lo sentimos, ocurrió un error, debe <a onclick=\"goUpdate();\">actualizar</a>.';` In your component change to this method `function goUpdate() { alert("Hola Mundo"); }`. All is native JavaScript when its compiled.

Comment: ya lo acabo de hacer, y al probar, puedo ver el link, presiono clic al link y no ejecuta la función.... algo que olvidé comentar es que toda la función goUpdate() está realizada en typescript, usé el Alert a manera de ejemplo....

Comment: Then don't use `DomSanitizer`. See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-sandbox-jrmm4n?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to pass the function call in the HTML string. In the example you tell me, I would only be passing a message to HTML. The solution you tell me is already developed, but it does not meet what I need ...